# Can't install local-build gcc-4.9.0 because of libgmp.so.3

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I am trying to install *gcc-4.9.0* in local-build on **linux** along with *gmp-4.3.2*, *mpfr-3.1.4* and *mpc-1.0.3* (I am following [this](http://openwall.info/wiki/internal/gcc-local-build) tutorial).

But when I run `make install` in the gcc build directory, I get this error :

```
test -z "/home/k.masson/gcc-4.9.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.0" || /usr/bin/mkdir -p "/home/k.masson/gcc-4.9.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.0"
Installing dummy lib libgcj_bc.so.1.0.0
/home/k.masson/build/gcc-4.9.0/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc/cc1:
```

Mainly this :

```
error while loading shared libraries: libgmp.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It seems that **libgmp.so.3 is not correctly installed** but it is ('make install'didn't failed for gmp) and I checked many times if the links were correct but nothing to do, I don't know why the make file don't find it.

Before running `make install`, I run these commands in the following order :

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/k.masson/gmp-4.3.2/lib:/home/k.masson/mpfr-2.4.2/lib:/home/k.masson/mpc-0.8.1/lib ./configure --prefix=/home/k.masson/gcc-4.9.0 --with-gmp=/home/k.masson/gmp-4.3.2 --with-mpfr=/home/k.masson/mpfr-2.4.2 --with-mpc=/home/k.masson/mpc-0.8.1 --disable-multilib
```

And this (I don't know why but this is in the tutorial):

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/k.masson/gmp-4.3.2/lib:/home/k.masson/mpfr-2.4.2/lib:/home/k.masson/mpc-0.8.1/lib nice -n 19 time make -j8
```

*libgmp.so.3* is in */home/k.masson/gmp-4.3.2/lib* as well as *libgmp.so.3.5.2*. I even tried to create the link myself with `ln -s libgmp.so.3.5.2 libgmp.so.3` but it doesn't fix the problem.

To install *gmp* in local-build, I used these commands :

```
./configure --prefix=/home/k.masson/gmp-4.3.2 --enable-cxx
nice -n 19 time make -j8
make install
make check
echo $?  # Returns 2
```

But **one test fail** :

```
====================================
1 of 58 tests failed
Please report to gmp-bugs@gmplib.org
====================================
make[4]: *** [check-TESTS] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/k.masson/build/gmp-4.3.2/tests/mpz'
make[3]: *** [check-am] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/k.masson/build/gmp-4.3.2/tests/mpz'
make[2]: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/k.masson/build/gmp-4.3.2/tests'
make[1]: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/k.masson/build/gmp-4.3.2'
make: *** [check] Error 2
```

Also, I got these few lines above when I'm running the tests:

```
/bin/sh: line 4: 20956 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ${dir}$tst
```

So I tried to install gmp-6.1.0 to avoid this test issue and it works, all tests are Ok but now, this is a gcc issue, I can't run `make install` anymore because the make file doesn't exists.. Should I keep the new gmp ? And change my gcc ? Or not at all ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: please be specific, you want help in installing `gcc` or `libgmp.so.3`??

Comment: You are trying to use gmp for gcc installation, which is not at all recommended...see https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC

Comment: Oh I see that.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The short way

To fix the test issue when installing *gmp*, I just choosed a **newer version** to install, it looked as a compatibility issue. So I picked up **[gmp-6.1.0](ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/)** and install and test processes were successful.

But this brought a new problem when installing *gcc-4.9.0*, the `./configure` wasn't able to generate a make file with a install procedure. So I had to get a newer version, I chose **[gcc-4.9.3](ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/releases/)** instead of *gcc-4.9.0* and everything works perfectly.

### The clean way

As [@piyush](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5469991/piyush-jaiswal) made me noticed, the short way is not recommended at all. See **[Installing GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC)**.

If you want to do a local-build, the best is to download the gcc version you want [here](ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/releases/) and before installing it, run the `./contrib/download_prerequisites` script in the gcc source.

If not, you can use your package manager, which is much better.